# Derive pandas column from another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column like following in my dataframe[image]

What I want is to create a new column based on the language column, like country, If someone's language is "eng", the country column should fill with UK

Desired output
[image]

NB: This is a sample I created in excel, I am working with pandas in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering this to be your df:

```
In [1359]: df = pd.DataFrame({'driver':['Hamilton', 'Sainz', 'Giovanazi'], 'language':['eng', 'spa', 'ita']})

In [1360]: df
Out[1360]: 
      driver language
0   Hamilton      eng
1      Sainz      spa
2  Giovanazi      ita
```

And this to be your language-country mapping:

```
In [1361]: mapping = {'eng': 'UK', 'spa': 'Spain', 'ita': 'Italy'}
```

You can use `df.map` to solve it:

```
In [1363]: df['country'] = df.language.map(mapping)

In [1364]: df
Out[1364]: 
      driver language country
0   Hamilton      eng      UK
1      Sainz      spa   Spain
2  Giovanazi      ita   Italy
```